# What does it mean when there’s a green join in place of where the camera is on the right hand corner for FaceTime

Tags: iphone

Does it mean there’s a conversation going on already

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot I don’t understand what green dot

Comment: Are you asking about a green dot in the status bar on iPhone? A green indicator means either the camera or the camera and the microphone are being used by an app on your iPhone.